# Loading data from observableArray one-by-one clicking button

Tags: knockout.js

I just came across a nice sample code for knockout.js and I am learning. So I am curious to understand the code flow. When I try to read that code then I stuck to understand a specific area. Here is the jsFiddle link from where anyone can see the full code http://jsfiddle.net/rustam/SSBZs/

```
//this two area now clear
  this.currentQuestion = ko.computed(function(){
     return self.questions()[self.questionIndex()];
  });

this.nextQuestion = function(){
  var questionIndex = self.questionIndex();
  if(self.questions().length - 1 > questionIndex){
    self.questionIndex(questionIndex + 1);
  }
};

this.prevQuestion = function(){
  var questionIndex = self.questionIndex();
  if(questionIndex > 0){
    self.questionIndex(questionIndex - 1);
  }
};
```

When clicking next or previous button then this two function is getting called `prevQuestion & nextQuestion` from this two routine `questionIndex` value is getting changed and accordingly question and answer set is changing.

My problem is there is no link between `questions and questionIndex` so I like to know when `questionIndex` is getting change then how question set is changing ?

Please help me to understand that how new or old question set is loaded when we click on next or prev button.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Questions are not changing, only current question is getting changed because it's a [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) value.

```
this.currentQuestion = ko.computed(function(){
     return self.questions()[self.questionIndex()];
});
```

And it depends on `questionIndex`, so every time `questionIndex` is changed `currentQuestion` is re-calculated.

Comment: very honestly i just do not understand the flow. if possible guide me how question and answer is loading when user clicking on next and prev button easy way. thanks

Comment: @Thomas, to understand how it works base on the above answer, please read about observables and computer observables in knockoutjs.